# How to register .NET 5 ClassLibrary for COM interop

Tags: c#, .net, com-interop

Hi I'm trying to register simple Class library for COM interop using .NET 5.

Here is my class code:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ComTestNET5
{
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [Guid("DB1797F5-7198-4411-8563-D05F4E904956")]

    public class HelloWrold
    {
        public void SayHello()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello .NET 5");
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <RegisterForComInterop>true</RegisterForComInterop>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

If I remove RegisterForComInterop library can by compiled and create dll file, but when i try to register it I get this error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>
> Error MSB3217 Cannot register assembly
>
> "C:\Users\denis\source\repos\ComTest\ComTest\bin\Debug\net5.0\ComTest.dll".
> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=5.0.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
> dependencies. The system cannot find the file
> specified.    ComTest C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets 5202

When I use .NET framework 4.8 I can set few settings in project properties and library will get registered. These settings are missing when building for .NET 5. Is it not possible to register com library from Visual Studio using .NET 5?

I tried to register it using regsvr32 but my project don't create ComTest.comhost.dll.

Edit:
I missed `<EnableComHosting>true</EnableComHosting>` line, now I can register it using regsvr32. But my question still stands, can't it be done automatically as with .NET framework and Visual Studio?

Comment: Why don't you try the official tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/native-interop/expose-components-to-com

Comment: I was looking at that tutorial and forgot mention that i tryed registered it using regsvr32 but my project don't create ComTest.comhost.dll.

Comment: The tutorial works fine. Make sure you've added <EnableComHosting>true</EnableComHosting>

Comment: Sorry I missed <EnableComHosting>true</EnableComHosting> line, now I can registered it using regsvr32. But my question still stands, can't it be done automaticaly as with .NET framework?

Comment: I don't think so, but you can add custom build steps the way you want.

Comment: Thank you I set up after build step to ran command and it workes, but I must not forget to run VS with elevated privileges.